# How to build asp.net core docker image externally

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to build asp.net core 6.0 image externally from the published code outside of docker image.

I am referring following code from https://docs.docker.com/samples/dotnetcore/

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
  FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 as base
  WORKDIR /App
  ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080
  COPY bin/Release/net6.0/publish/ App/
  ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "App/test-app.dll"]
```

Here container is created successfully, but when I try to access http://localhost:< portnumber>
then it's not reachable.(**note**: this portnumber, I have defined in dockerfile using environment variable i.e. ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080). Also I have verified the files which copied from publish, while running container and they are copied well.

Comment: You need to map the port to a host port when you run the container. Also, you say that you've defined the environment variable in the Dockerfile, but it's not in the Dockerfile you show. It would be nice to see the `docker run` command you use to run the container. You also say that your app is .NET 6.0, but the image you use is 5.0.

Comment: I have updated the my current code.